# How can I mock another web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have code that calls a web service.  We'll say a "3rd party" web service.  So I can get the wsdl for this service, in fact I've generated a proxy class using this wsdl.

The requirement that I'm trying to meet is this: Create a web service that LOOKS just like the above mentioned one, but does other stuff.  So the web service URL will be changed in a config file/database, to allow switching between the two web services.

What I'm not sure about is how I can use that proxy class that I generated, or some other method, so that the namespacing and data contract look exactly the same.  I don't know much about this and these are terms that colleagues have tossed out there.  I only need to actually implement one of the web service's methods in my version.

Comment: How are you consuming this webservice?  Perhaps you can use dependency injection to pass in an interface that the service implements and then mock it up that way.

Comment: Maybe something like.. 'Hey there web service, I bet you can't parse any JSON, or perform any async calls...'

Answer (score 0):

Build site with any technology you know of and return responses that match that service.

Note that if you just need to return static enough responses for occasional testing you can use Fiddler as it allows to return arbitrary responses instead of real once.